# MVC OutputCache issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, outputcache

I am trying to cache the output of a controller action in MVC2 like this:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 600, VaryByParam = "id", Location=System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.Server)]
        public FileContentResult GetImage(int id) {
}
```

When the user uploads a new image for their icon I invalidate the cache using the following line:

```
HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem("/MyPage/GetImage/" + u.UserID.ToString());
```

However this doesn't seem to work and I can't figure out why

Comment: Your code looks correct. Can you validate that `u.UserID.ToString()` is returning the correct id?

Comment: Yep it's definitely returning the correct id

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about that but it appears to me that even if you use "Location=server" it might still cache at the client (as if there was no outputCache attribute at all) unless there is also "NoStore=true".

As such the problem might be a result of client side caching.

You can check if this is the case by examining the client side requests by using debugging tools such as fiddler or the ones that are built in into the browsers.

Comment: To verify this, use your browser's debug tool network (net) view and look for a 304 status for the GetImage call. A 304 means the browser is not going back to the server. To overcome this, you can add a timestamp as an extra parameter to the call.

Comment: @Steve While adding an extra parameter will certainly force to request the image directly it will do so even when the image has not been changed as well, which is against the reason he placed an OutputCache attribute at the first place

Comment: I understand your logic, and you are prob correct, but it's possible the server would then kick in with it's caching mechanism when the browser did the request. I'm guessing - can't test it right now.

Comment: @Steve you are probably right with that point, after all this is what VaryByParam is all about, and after all the OutputCache attribute is set to Location="server" so he wasn't so much looking for client side caching.